# How can I add title to this radar chart?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px


df = px.data.iris()


categories = ['PSxG-GA','Goals Against','Save %',
              'Clean Sheet %', 'Save %(penalty)']

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
      r=[79, 79, 85, 86, 19],
      theta=categories,
      fill='toself',
      name='MATS'
))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
      r=[89, 96, 92, 95, 81],
      theta=categories,
      fill='toself',
      name='Oblak'
))


fig.update_layout(
  polar=dict(
    radialaxis=dict(
      visible=True,
      range=[0, 100]
    )),
  showlegend=False
)

fig.show()
```

and this is the result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJkK0.png)

I am trying to make a radar chart comparing two soccer players Ter Stegen and Oblak. I have made the chart but am struggling to add a title and assign which color is for whom on the side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
fig.update_layout(title_text = 'Title')
```

Or:

```
fig.update_layout(title = dict(text = 'Title'))
```

#### Plot

[image]

Comment: it would be really helpful if you could tell me how to add a label as well. like two lines on top right. orange line assigned to Oblak and purple line assigned to Ter stegen. Thank you

Comment: Please don't change the title of the question after having received an answer. I would be happy to help you further, but one question per post is the preferred way.

Comment: sorry. changed back the title of the question. i am actually new here and am not sure how things work yet,

Comment: Absolutely no problem! Your question was unusually good for a first post, in that it had a clear and focused question with a reproducible data sample. So you're off to a good start!